# How to find out how long it takes the linux kernel to respond to IRQs?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, interrupt

How could I measure how long it takes the linux kernel to respond to IRQs?

I could trigger a keyboard IRQ and start counting the time but how to find out when the ISR is finished?

Comment: Do you mean the time difference between when the IRQ is actually fired (via electric signals) and the end of top half/ISR? Can't you use `jiffies` if you can simulate an IRQ? AFAIK there is no way to measure the time of an actual interrupt, unless the IRQ firing device is also cooperative.

Comment: [systemtap](https://sourceware.org) may be of use to you here. It's a very powerful dynamic tracing framework. Allows you to dynamically insert probes into both user and kernel code and execute a script. Relevant to your question is that it can probe both isr start and end. Example script [here](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/process/cycle_thief.stp)

Comment: @holgac That's basically what I tried to measure. For example the time between a keyboard key is pressed until the ISR has finished. But I'd probably have to do some research since I'm new to this whole kernel stuff. Maybe someone on SO can help.

Comment: @AlanAu I've heard of systemtap, seems to be worth looking into. Thanks for the link.

Comment: ftrace or kprobe/jprobe can be helpful go thru the documentation